# What's the purpose of the `sut` variable in this code? Why doesn't the second snippet without it work?

Tags: c

This function prints a rectangle of `X` characters:

```
void kutu_ciz( int line, int column ) {
    int sut;
    for ( ; line > 0; line--) {
        for (sut = column; sut > 0; sut--)
            printf("X");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

This version without `sut` doesn't work. Why not? What's the difference?

```
void kutu_ciz( int line, int column ) {
    for ( ; line > 0; line--) {
        for (; column > 0; column--)
            printf("X");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should always show in the question the input you use, the expected output and the actual output. Explain what "works"/"doesn't work" means.

Answer (score 1):

The second version "looks" good because it has pleasing symmetry in the two `for` loops. It doesn't work, though, because after the inner loop runs once the `column` variable ends up set to `0`. The next time the inner loop runs `column` has lost its initial value and is permanently `0`. This causes only the first row of the rectangle to print and the rest to be blank.